# How do I represent medication alternatives in FHIR?

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hl7-fhir

I would like to know if there is a Resource I could use to represent medication alternatives, such as:

If you are taking Drug A , you should use Drug B or Drug C instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something that FHIR has implemented yet - it's clinical/medical knowledge. The nearest that FHIR currently has is the Clinical Quality Framework: http://hl7-fhir.github.io/cqif/cqif.html

Warning: It's very much a work in progress, and the link above is to the current build, not a stable release

Comment: Thanks, and I appreciate sharing the link.